# Shopify Notification: How to link product image & name to the product page in email notifications?

Tags: email, shopify

Trying to link product in the email notifications.

I want the customer to be able to click on the ordered item image/name & link it to item's product page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Try something like this:

```
{% for line in line_items %} 
  ...
  <a href="{{ shop.url | append: line.product.url }}">{{ line.title }}</a>
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

I appended the product url onto the shop url because [`product.url`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/product#product-url) returns a relative url. If the customer is accessing the link from an email you need to include the full url.

Comment: @MayaChen no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and very simple, as long as the default Shopify notification module.

In your store admin panel, go to Settings -> Notifications and select the mail template as you wish.

Follow the liquid references mentioned on this link - [Email variable reference](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/notifications/email-variables), and create your own HTML/Plain text template.